# What is the best deep learning library for scala?

Tags: deep-learning, scala

Does any one has a recommendation for what libraries to use for deep learning?

Comment: [mxnet](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/scala-package) and [tensorflow](https://github.com/mskimm/tensorflow-scala) (unofficial bindings)

Comment: Scorch is a simple neural net framework in Scala inspired by PyTorch. Scorch lives here: https://github.com/botkop/scorch

Answer (score 6):

Hi (I created deeplearning4j: warning biased source),

It's fairly new but we are open to feedback. We ported keras to scala:
http://github.com/deeplearning4j/ScalNet/

This uses deeplearning4j underneath. We would love contributions or issues.

Answer (score 5):

I think currently there is no pure scala deep learning library which can be compared with mxnet, caffe, keras and etc.

For lang on JVM, u can try this one:
https://deeplearning4j.org/